# Why is the first sentence more correct than the other?

Tags: grammar, questions

Started a English B2 course on this site PerfectlySpoken.
Came across these two sentences, which one is correct is the question of the exercise, the teacher said the first one is, but I did not understand why. In my brain both make sense for some reason.

I have had a headache all morning.  -> Correct
I have been having a headache all morning.  -> Incorrect

Comment: I guess it is nicer to show the effort you already made, such as 
grammar rules and examples 
in a dictionary or other trusted reference.

Comment: Obviously composed by people who don't know English well. Or else don't care whether other people learn it well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "I have a headache", you are talking about your current state of suffering from that affliction. To say "I'm having a headache" adds nothing to the statement, and it is not idiomatic. The same thing applies to "have had" - making it progressive adds nothing and is not idiomatic.
Compare to "I have a cold." That's correct and complete. You wouldn't say "I'm having a cold."